# RottenTomatoes movies ranked by audience

Tags: rotten-tomatoes

RottenTomatoes has a [top movies](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/top/) page. However, the ranking is based on the "Tomatometer" score. Instead, I would like the list of top movies by "audience" score. (Each movie has Tomatometer and audience scores.)

How can I rank movies by audience score on RottenTomatoes?

Comment: The [API](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/) provides `audience_score` so some list should be possible and you can make up to 10,000 API calls per day.

Comment: @Gareth: Interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to sort movies by audience score using the RottenTomatoes interface. However, as mentioned by @Gareth, `audience_score` is accessible through the [Rotten Tomatoes API](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/).

Obviously, in order to rank movies by `audience_score` you need to obtain the scores for a given set of movies and sort them appropriately. In ["Rotten Tomatoes Audience Scores"](http://rawdust.com/rotten/rotten-tomatoes-audience-scores.htm) on [rawdust](http://rawdust.com), the author created a python script to do this for the `top_rentals` list for the top 50 movies (this list is among the DVD Lists in the [IO Docs](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/iodocs) and you could do the same using the list of top movies per the Box Office etc.).

The full python script is available [here](http://rawdust.com/rotten/Rotten.py). (note: I'm not sure if it's "kosher" to cut and paste someone else's script in full here. If so, I'll edit appropriately).